# Laravel error on merge collection later to upgrate from 4.0 to 4.1

Tags: collections, laravel, merge, laravel-4

Later to upgrade Laravel version i found that the `Collection::merge` method isn't working well.

Not sure if it is my problem, i can't find an error. Lets see some information:

```
print_r($ecb->count());
print_r($boc->count());

// merge both
$cubes = $ecb->merge($boc);

print_r($cubes->count());
dd();
```

output:

> 36   27   1

the merge should to give like output 36 + 27 (there isn't duplicate element on the collection)

More debug information:

```
print_r($ecb->toArray());
print_r($boc->toArray());

// merge both
$cubes = $ecb->merge($boc);

print_r($cubes->toArray());
dd();
```

output (is a bit long): http://laravel.io/bin/PdVj1#7

Any idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it appears to have changed between 4 and 4.1

See this Github issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3445

In essence Eloquent collections, upon merging, remove models with duplicate primary keys.

I'm running Laravel 4.1.29 - and I get a different output to you with count() - but in essence it just removes duplicate ids.

Answer (score 1):

I see that in Laravel 4.1 merge delete element with same ids ( https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3445 )

To have the same behavior i should to change the code like it:

```
$boc->each(function($cube) use ($ecb)
{
    $ecb->push($cube);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The merge function uses `Model#getKey()` to differentiate different models - do the models you are using have a primary key specified properly? I notice they don't have the standard `id` field.